# Медленный ли Symfony?

Tags: php, производительность, symfony, phalcon

В данный момент, решил попробовать Symfony 3 на PHP 7, и задаюсь вопросом производительности.

Есть задача написания REST API, решил попробовать Symfony 3, написал тестовое API и попробовал выполнить тест Apache AB (**ab -t 10 -c 10**) на **несуществующий** метод, скорость обработки **2062** запроса за 10 секунд или **206** запросов в секунду.

Делаю тоже самое на Phalcon, скорость **23297** запросов за 10 секунд или **2329.69 запросов в секунду**. Если запускать один запрос, то скорость одинаковая, **примерно 90** мс.

В чем прикол? Может я что-то делаю неправильно и где-то нужно настроить что-то, чтобы на несуществующий запрос была более высокая скорость или это нормальная скорость? Я понимаю, что Symfony имеет высокую абстракцию, за нее нужно платить, и поэтому производительность меньше, но тут просто нужно просто **вывести 404** ошибку и такой сумасшедший отрыв.

**Отрыв Phalcon становится меньше**, если взять и добавить операцию поиска в базу и маппинга, через модель встроенную в фреймворк. Phalcon правда всеравно быстрее, 1600 запросов против 900 запросов Symfony за 10 секунд.

**Конфигурация:** PHP 7, Debian, opcache on, Symfony3, Phalcon 3, Кеш Symfony включен, режим Production.

**Подключенные бандлы в Symfony:**

```
new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
new Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle()
```

**app.php:**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

---

Ладно, делаем замеры потребляемых ресурсов при выполнении запроса в базу данных **на поиск и маппинг**:

Выполняем замер Symfony и существующей конфигурации PHP-FPM при работе Apache AB (**ab -t 10 -c 10**):

```
20383 www-data 20 0 380884 26040 18020 R **58,3** 0,3 0:10.35 php-fpm7.0
21394 www-data 20 0 380884 26040 18020 R **57,3** 0,3 0:03.62 php-fpm7.0
21498 www-data 20 0 380884 25908 17900 R **57,3** 0,3 0:02.77 php-fpm7.0
19479 www-data 20 0 380884 25020 18020 D **55,7** 0,3 0:15.08 php-fpm7.0
20481 www-data 20 0 380884 26044 18020 R **52,0** 0,3 0:09.30 php-fpm7.0
```

Окей, в среднем FPM жрет **52 процента** ядра на каждый процесс, делаем замер Phalcon:

```
24110 www-data 20 0 379016 17876 12848 S **13,6** 0,2 0:03.57 php-fpm7.0
25593 www-data 20 0 378884 17776 12848 R **13,3** 0,2 0:02.30 php-fpm7.0
27023 www-data 20 0 378884 17608 12788 S **13,3** 0,2 0:01.08 php-fpm7.0
25445 www-data 20 0 378884 17780 12848 S **13,0** 0,2 0:02.48 php-fpm7.0
27177 www-data 20 0 378884 17600 12788 R **13,0** 0,2 0:00.91 php-fpm7.0
```

Phalcon не грузит систему, при одинаковых действиях, загрузка на каждый процесс **13 процентов**.

Я могу предположить, что возможно скорость меньше и нагрузка выше из-за того, что Symfony дергает кеш с диска каждый раз, а Phalcon по умолчанию все пишет в память. Если это так, то как перенести весь кеш в память, чтобы исключить нагрузку на диск?

Кто разбирается в Symfony, скажите, как сделать его быстрее и возможно ли это? В чем ошибка?

Comment: Разрыв в 1.7 - это О(1), на большом приложении и того будет меньше, я не очень хорошо понимаю, чего вы добиваетесь. Да, в симфони будет физически выполняться больше кода, если хотите посмотреть, где реально тормозит - стоит взять xhprof или xdebug + cachegrind

Comment: И да, concurrency = 10 - это вообще ни о чем, тут все будет упираться в продолжительность запроса.

Comment: @Etki concurrency = 350 (поиск в базе, маппинг) - Phalcon = 1800 r/10s (15% CPU), Symfony3 (1000 r/10s, 70% CPU). Про производительность на большом приложении понятно, но загрузка процессора и скорость на несуществующем запросе не меняется. Вопрос состоит в том, что можно как-то ускорить запрос на несуществующий URL (regexp без загрузки ядра?) без костылей, и есть ли способы как-то снизить нагрузку на процессор от тяжеловесного фреймворка? Понимаю, что видимо нет, это расплата за абстракции на PHP :)

Comment: Я не могу сказать, что там проивходит при возврате 404, но, честно говоря, вас это опять же пугать не должно, т.к. при работе приложения 99% запросов не попадают на несуществующий путь.

Comment: А микрофреймворк симфони не тестировали?

Comment: А зачем вам для REST API Symfony? Можно же что-то повеселей использовать, например Silex.

Comment: @danil не успел, но планирую посмотреть, как он будет себя вести на нагрузке, должно быть быстрее.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev захотелось попробовать что-то новое в новом проекте, по разбираться. В основном проекты на Phalcon, вот решил выбрать что-то более мощное и популярное для разработки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

фалькон быстрый потому, что написан как расширение для PHP на С

Да, симфони очень медленный, вовсе не по тому, что "Symfony дергает кеш с диска каждый раз, а Phalcon по умолчанию все пишет в память.", а потому, что представляет собой достаточно толстую прослойку уймы абстракций.

Нет, невозможно. Они предназначены для разных задач. Удобство клепать мелкие сайты с модным MVC  на Симфони vs условно-хардкорная производительность чистых сей для фалькона.

и нет, у вас не получится как-то супер-быстро разрешать нагрузку на на существующий урл, если все урлы обрабатывает симфони, если урл дошел от веб-сервера до симфони, она его еще как обработает. Придется решать проблему несуществующих урлов как-то по-другому (на стороне веб-сервера)

Сделать симфоню быстрее можно, наверное, настроив правильное кэширование (opcache), но тем не менее, с фальконом она не сможет соревноваться по скорости.

Т.е. даже симфоневый раутинг (я про 404) будет медленней фальконовского.

Кроме того, использование Апача в качестве сервера для хайлоада не oche рекомендуется (возможно, он, конечно, вырос за последние годы)

P.S. Как  я уже говорил, 36 тысяч вызовов функции substr на один http запрос в Симфони... ну.. окей.

Comment: Используется nginx+php-fpm7.0 с настроенным OpCache. Просто много пишут, что в PHP 7 разницы нет по ресурсам и производительности, а тут оказывается и нагрузка на процессор больше, и кол-во запросов меньше, вот я и подумал, может я где-то накосячил в конфигурации и что-то меняет волшебная строка, но видимо нет.

Comment: нет, просто в симфони слишком много абстракций и чистого пхп. Кому-то удобно, кому-то нет. Но скорость - дичайше падает.

Answer (score 2):

Привет из 2018, Symfony 4 теперь мега крутой, мощный и при этом быстрый микрофреймворк со своим Flex плагином для Composer-а и конкурентов 0.